# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and authenticationManager() are not working now ,how i can change it to work in the new version

Tags: security, web, adapter, deprecated

i want to change it because  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not work any more
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
  private final UserService userDetailsService;
  private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
  
  public WebSecurity(UserService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,  SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));  
        
}
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}
```

Comment: i put my projrct if any one wants to see it :https://github.com/SidaneWafi/securityy.git